# What is known about powers of 2 satisfying the Goldbach condition?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Despite searching in many ways, I have not been able to find any information regarding whether or not powers of 2 can be demonstrated to satisfy the Goldbach condition, i.e. always being expressible as the sum of two primes. Powers of 2 are a rather small subset of all even  numbers, but they have the unique property of being composite but containing no odd prime factors. Has anyone come across commentary, or better, proof, regarding the conformity of powers of 2 to the Goldbach condition?

Comment: The factorization of an even number has little to do with the possibility to write is as the sum of two primes. So I do not see why the powers of $2$ should be *special*.

Comment: On the other hand the factorization has *very much* to do with the possibility to write $n$ as $a^2+b^2$ or $a^2+2b^2$ or $a^2+3b^2$, since some peculiar quadratic fields have class number one. But in dealing with the sum of two primes we lack such wonderful connection given by the Lagrange-Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well, the singular series constant in the (heuristic) asymptotic for the number of representations of $N$ as the sum of two primes does depend on the factorization of $N$.  The powers of $2$ are in some weak sense the worst case, as for each odd prime $p$ there is a non-zero residue $a$ mod $p$ such that $N-a$ is divisible by $p$.  But the difference is rather slight as a function of $N$.

Comment: Still, given that it is in some sense the "hardest" case, there's no particularly reason to single them out and ask whether Goldbach holds on that restricted subset, since the answer is not expected to be different from the general population.